# XGBoost Cross Validation with different cut point

Tags: java, machine-learning, xgboost

I would like to create two models of binary prediction: one with the cut point strictly greater than 0.5 (in order to obtain fewer signals but better ones) and second with the cut point strictly less than 0.5.

Doing the cross-validation, we have a test error related to the cut point equal to 0.5. How can I do it with other cut value? I talk about XGBoost for Java.

Comment: Do you mean using a different threshold? in one case, when threshold > 0.5 then 1 otherwise 0, and in 2nd case when threshold < 0.5 then 0 otherwise 1?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

xgboost returns a list of scores. You can do what ever you want to that list of scores.
I think that particularly in Java, it returns a 2d `ArrayList` of shape `(1, n)`

In binary prediction you probably used a logistic function, thus your scores will be between 0 to 1.

Take your scores object and create a custom function that will calculate new **predictions**, by the rules you've described.

If you are using an automated/xgboost-implemented Cross Validation Function, you might want to build a customized evaluation function which will do as you bid, and pass it as an argument to `xgb.cv`

If you want to be smart when setting your threshold, I suggest reading about **AUC of Roc Curve** and **Precision Recall Curve**.